# How to evaluate row-wise expressions (like df.eval() but dynamic) contained in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming you have a DataFrame with a column containing expressions (referring to other columns),  is it possible to evaluate the expressions contained in that column?

I know one can use `pd.eval()` and `df.eval()` to apply column-wise operations (as seen below). Example taken from:

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html

Assuming you have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

then you can write:

```
df.eval('(A + B)')
```

and you will get a series with `3, 5, 11` (expected).

Now what if that expression actually varies from row to row and is actually stored as a column? Such as this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "A + B"], [2, 3, "A - B"], [5, 6, "A + 2 * B"]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

How does one go about evaluating the expressions in column C?

The expected result in that case is a series with `3, -1, 17`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could simply loop over each row couldn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
>>> np.diag(df.C.apply(df.eval).values)

array([ 3, -1, 17])
```

Even though this is a bad design IMO, since you're I) hardcoding operations in a string, making it harder to manipulate it in case you need, II) Storing these operations as string in a pandas `DataFrame`, which is slow for many string-involved operations.

Comment: This works like a charm. Agreed, this comes from a business requirement where such expressions are manually entered (AI assisted human-interface). ie, I am not hardcoding the expressions but rather have to deal with them ;).

Thanks for your help!